# Wild card in oc command line resource names

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

Trying to delete all imagestreams which has prefix filebeat:-

```
λ oc delete imagestream 'filebeatbuilder*'
```

which is returning error:-
Error from server (NotFound): imagestreams.image.openshift.io "'filebeatbuilder*'" not found

Ask is can we have wildcard in resource name?

Answer (score 0):

To delete all the imagestreams resources that prefixes with `filebeatbuilder` you can use

```
oc delete imagestream $(oc get imagestream | grep filebeatbuilder | awk '{print $1}')
```

Suppose I create `imagestream` resources filebeatbuilder**X** (**X** in (1,2,3,4)) and run the above `oc delete` command, it will result in

```
imagestream.image.openshift.io "filebeatbuilder1" deleted
imagestream.image.openshift.io "filebeatbuilder2" deleted
imagestream.image.openshift.io "filebeatbuilder3" deleted
imagestream.image.openshift.io "filebeatbuilder4" deleted
```